# How do I use this config.yml file to run a web scraper that someone else built?

Tags: docker, web-scraping, yaml, config

My end goal: I want to fetch data from a retail site on an hourly schedule to see if a specific product is back in stock or not.

I tried using xpath in python to scrape the site myself, but I'm not too familiar, and why reinvent the wheel if someone built a scraper already? In this case, Diggernaut has a github repo.

https://github.com/Diggernaut/configs/tree/master/bananarepublic.gap.com

I'm using the above github repo to try and run a pre-existing web scraper on the banana republic retail site. All that's included in the folder is a config.yml file. I don't even know where to start to try and run it... I am not familiar with using .yml files at all, barely know my way around a terminal (I can do basic "ls" and "cd" and "brew install", otherwise, no idea).

Help! I have docker and git installed (not that I know how to use docker). I have a Mac version 10.13.6 (High Sierra).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're looking at using Docker for this, as the config.yml is designed for use on Diggernaut.com and not as part of a docker container deployment. In fact, there is no docker container for Diggernaut that exists as far as I can see.

On the main Github config page for Diggernaut they list the following instructions:

```
All configs can be used with Diggernaut service to retrieve products information.

You need to create free account at Diggernaut
Login to your account
Create a project with any name and description you want
Get into your new project by clicking it and create new digger with any name
Then you will see 3 options suggested to you, you need to use one where you will use meta-language
Config editor will open and you can simply copy and paste config code and click on save button.
Switch mode for digger from Debug to Active and then run your digger.
Wait for completion.
Download data.
Schedule your runs if required.
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that. After trying the scraper, I receive the following message:
Page content: <html><head><title>Access Denied</title></head><body><h1>Access Denied</h1> You don&#39;t have permission to access &#34;http://bananarepublic.gap.com/&#34; on this server.<p>Reference #18.4aa2617.1593628066.1729629b</p></body></html>

Comment: Looks like I'll have to try to do it on my own after all!